# Can I use 6LoWPAN to tether BLE devices with Android?

Tags: bluetooth-tethering, 8.1-oreo, ipv6, bluetooth-le

I have a Nexus 5X (running stock firmware) which [supports Bluetooth 4.2](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6102470?hl=en).  How do I use [6LoWPAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6LoWPAN) to share the internet from my phone with BLE devices?

Is it as simple as enabling Bluetooth tethering in settings?